# MSSQL connection in XAMPP under OSX El Capitan

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, osx-elcapitan

i try installing MSSQL extension for PHP in XAMPP under OSX El capitan, but i have a problem. Its not working.

Error log write:

> [18-Apr-2016 10:40:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
>   to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mssql.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mssql.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mssql.so
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: mssql.so requires version 7.0.0
>   or later, but libsybdb.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0 in Unknown on
>   line 0 [18-Apr-2016 10:40:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_dblib.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_dblib.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_dblib.so
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: pdo_dblib.so requires version
>   7.0.0 or later, but libsybdb.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0 in Unknown on line 0

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Reason: Incompatible library version: mssql.so requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libsybdb.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0

Reason: Incompatible library version: pdo_dblib.so requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libsybdb.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0